# Migration Relationship To-One to To-Many Result on Empty NSSet

Tags: swift, core-data, database-migration, magicalrecord

I encounter a problem when I migrate models.

Firstly, I had a user with an article. I made models like this:

[image: Model v1]

Now, I made a second version for the models like this:

[image: Model v2]

And in my `AppDelegate`, I call `MagicalRecord.setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack()`.

The migration works, but the article list on `user` is empty.

Does anyone know how to automatically set the list with the previous article set on `user`?

Comment: thanks @ZGski for the edit and grammar fix. My english isn't very good that help me to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should set relationship type on `user` is "To many", and relationship type on `article` is "To one".

This will provide you an **One-many relationship** on the database which means one user can have many articles.

For accessing array of articles in first user, use:

```
let user = User.mr_findFirst()!
let articleList = user.article?.allObjects as! [Article]
for anArticle in articleList {
     // Do something here
}
```

Or in all users:

```
let userList = User.mr_findAll() as! [User]
for user in userList {
     let articleList = user.article?.allObjects as! [Article]
     for anArticle in articleList {
          // Do something here
     }
}
```